# ireport - Erro ao usar Print When Expression

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

Estou com um problema ao gerar o relatório, não funciona a função `print when expression`, sempre o relatório mostra essa linha com o valor `null`

Estou fazendo assim na linha

```
<printWhenExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($F{codProduto} != null)]]></printWhenExpression>
```

mas sempre o relatório aparece essa linha em `cinza` escrito `null`:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como posso resolver essa situação?

Answer (score 0):

Tente escrever a expressão assim:

```
<printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{codProduto} != null]]></printWhenExpression>
```